# Visual Studio 2010 Sequence Diagrams Cannot load

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml, sequence-diagram

I was editing a VS 2010 Sequence Diagram and after saving and closing it, I can no longer open it. I get the following error. Anyone know how to resolve this?

> "Cannot Load '{diagram path and name}': Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: rolePlayer"

The title of the dialog is "Microsoft Visual Studio"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on the [MSDN Visualization & Modeling Tools forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/thread/afb6103f-a22a-4a67-ad95-62405a0954b6).

Comment: Wow, who knew these forums were integrated. Well, that's Microsoft for you... integrate, integrate, integrate. Nice one.